# Currency localization and handling in C#

Tags: c#, javascript

I am looking for a strategy to implement different currencies in my system.

For GB I use pounds locale and it works ok with numbers like "7.55", but as soon I change locale to Spanish for example I get the "7,55" number and I cannot handle it.

So the first thing is that I calculate some amount with JavaScript client side and JavaScript cannot calculate comma numbers, nor I can parseFloat, nor converting to decimal number if I don't replace commas with numbers like:

```
input.val().replace(',', '.');
```

I mean I don't understand how to handle this properly in scenarios when you have to make payment. When to convert for calculations, etc.

Is there any proper way to do this in .net with JavaScript help? Just need some tips.

Answer (score 0):

In c#, you can use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` for this. You have a full snippet about currency [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#code-snippet-2).

```
string str = "42.5";
float numFloat = float.Parse(str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Learn more from the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).